# spring security remember me authentication is not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm new to java programing language and I'm trying to implement the remember-me token authentication.

I'm implementing [this example](http://keylesson.com/index.php/2016/04/13/spring-security-rememberme-example-2719/) except I want to test it by calling a controller not from a

> login.jsp

I also want to know from where the `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` class is been called? From the bean in the xml file or from the controller?

thank you in advance.

Comment: any suggestion concerning my question? @jean

Comment: I don't play with java but your Token is likely being called by the Spring itself (look the declaration). Keep learning, in time you ill realize those answers by yourself

Comment: okey i will , thank you for your advice @jean